# filtering table using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I Have a table which is displayed using knockout. I have a textbox used to search the table in client side. Based on the search text box i need to filter table.
I am using Knockout version -knockout-3.4.0.js. Most of the sample available based on the old version of knockout. Do we have any easy way to achieve the desired
result. In the Table there are around  4 columns and each columns will have a group of 3 fiels. So basically i need to search all the group of fields in each column 
and update the result in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think you want the ko.utils.arrayFilter as defined here.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

here is a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/23/

here is the filter copied from the knockout utility function website listed above.

```
//filter the items using the filter text
viewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
    var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
    if (!filter) {
        return this.items();
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
            return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.name().toLowerCase(), filter);
        });
    }
}, viewModel);
```